# Forbidding pushes on Git/Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there any plugin for distributed SCMs that forbids pushing code that doesn't fulfil a certain criteria (e.g. min test coverage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both current answers address Mercurial; with git, there are also hooks, and you will want either the pre-receive or update hook. See the [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) man page for information.

Be careful using them to check for things like test coverage, though - you don't want the user to have to wait for time-consuming tests to run while attempting to push.

Answer (score 3):

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks states that for server-side checking you could use update hooks.

You should place hooks in your central main repository of course.

Comment: The OP asks about pushing, not committing. Of course, maybe that was just an inaccurate word choice... either way, we agree, use hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pre-commit/pre-changeset hook.

The [hgrc Man Page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) has some info. Probably better is the [hg book section on hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html).

Comment: pre-commit won't catch pushes, and pre-changeset doesn't have access to the incoming changesets.  pretxnchangegroup is probably what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

In mercurial, you'll want to use [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html).  Use a controlling hook on the server side, `pretxnchangegroup` most likely.  Here's a good example of a hook that prevents someone from doing a push that creates multiple heads: http://hg.netbeans.org/nb-hooks/file/tip/forbid_2head.py